# Royden's Lebesgue Integration 4.4 #34

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a nonegative measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^{n} f=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f}
\end{equation}

Of course $$\forall n, \int_{-n}^{n} f \leq\int_{\mathbb{R}} f$$

To show the reverse, I feel that I need to use Fatou's lemma; but can't seem to get the right argument. This problem is found in Royden's *Real Analysi*s 4th edition, p. 90, #34.

Comment: Try monotone convergence instead. (Fatou's lemma works, too)

Comment: Yes, the sequence of integrals are increasing, but I don't have pointwise convergence a.e. to $\int_R f$.

Comment: The sequence of integrals is not your main concern. The sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(-n, n)}$ is your main concern.

Comment: Great! Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of integrals is not your main concern. The sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(-n, n)}$ is your main concern.

Answer (score 2):

You may apply the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) with
$$
\int_{-n}^{n} f=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(-n, n)} \leq\int_{\mathbb{R}} f
$$ and you may conclude easily.

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$ or the monotone convergence theorem. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Olivier Oloa's answer says you should use the dominated convergence theorem.

Giuseppe Negro's answer says you should consider this sequence of functions:
$$
f_n(x)=f(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(-n, n)}. \tag 1
$$

I would have considered the sequence $(1)$ and applied the **monotone** convergence theorem.

However, the question of whether that is what you ought to do depends on the context.  Should you just cite and apply the theorem, or should you prove this particular instance of it from scratch?  If you haven't yet seen the theorem at that point in the book, maybe the latter.  If you have seen it and the exercise is phrased in a certain way, then also the latter.  If that section of the book was devoted to proving the monotone convergence theorem, then probably the former.